# how to make an enemy independently moved by an inverted screen movement made by the player

Tags: math, coordinates, mit-scratch, visual-programming

**What I'm trying to make**
In mit-scratch I'm making an Isometric game with an arena as the main part of the game idea, the player would be going around killing enemies while being unable to pass through objects. the enemies should be slower than the player but should provide a challenge non the less.

**problem**
I have succeeded in making the player appear as if it's moving across the screen and appear to hit objects, go behind them and reappear again when in front. (this is all based on the screen invertedly moving while the player stays in the center at 0,0) as the stage moves up the players' y position is less and at its max "1266" and at its least "0" since the enemy is *NOT* a stationary object and based on the movement of the player to determine its position, it ends up moving upward in the y axis to compensate for the movement of the player, the problem of this is the fact that when the enemy goes near an object it can hide behind, it will change layers dependent to that of the stage which causes the enemy to only go in front of objects when the player can and vise versa when the player cant. so I want the enemy to not change its y-axis when it gets further away from 0 but instead find its position on a grid and determine whether it should be in front or behind an object for itself.

**game mechanics**
as said in the problem of the matter sprites behind objects should be hidden the way this is done, is by removing 0 from the stage by adding the max value by itself so that when it reaches the top or bottom its always positive from "0-1266" (this number is always referring to the Y axis) the player would then start at this max number/2 and x=0 so they would naturally start at 0,0 in a sense. what the pillars (objects) do is they are all clones that take the value of the stage and compare it to their own starting value and determine if they should be above the player or behind by going to the back layer and moving up a certain number of layers thus creating the illusion that the player is in the arena.

**What I'm asking**
I'm not asking anybody who reads this to understand scratch or how it works but instead to solve the problem in a figurative sense of how you would solve it if you were doing it yourself, and then I would try to replicate your idea and hope it works.

it's very hard to visualize in my head but I've mostly played around with how the stage interacts with the y value of the player and I've mostly just tried some differencing trying to get rid of the distance from 0 from the center of the screen, so I made it figure out the distance from the player but this just did the same thing but made the center the player... and at this point, I don't know what to do...

Comment: Removing Java tag. Scratch has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: though it may not be directly java related it is based on the Java language and has the same process of execution, so i do believe it classifies to be in the Java category, before i edit it back, id wish a better explanation than that of what was given.

Comment: A question tagged Java has to be related to the Java language. A question tagged C has to be related to the C language. A relationship based on abstract concepts is not enough. Scratch is not implemented on Java, its execution model is different, everything is different about them, except that both are programming languages, when all programming languages would have some similar concepts at some point. That is not a relationship, unless you want to ask about generic concepts of programming languages.

Comment: alright, i agree with that, thanks for making it more clear. if you have any help you could provide on the question however that would be nice too.

Comment: Note that SO is not an idea board, so if you want people to ideate on how to solve your problem _conceptually_, this is not really the place for that. However, this _is_ a Q&A site for specific programming problems so give [the posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) a read through and then rewrite your post as a concrete problem: what did you set out to do, what ([mcve]) code did you write, what did that code do that you didn't expect it to, what did you already do in terms of debugging and (re)searching, and what specific thing that's blocking you from getting unstuck do you need help with?

Comment: I had trouble understanding your question, but I suppose you are working on a way to make 'nearby' sprites appear in front of sprites that are further away. Griffpatch is the expert on this. To help scratchers like yourself, he has made a video tutorial and various projects. Start by visiting this studio: https://scratch.mit.edu/studios/30691931

Comment: im aware of griffpatch but probably wont get ahold of him by normal means, but thanks for trying to solve the problem, i haven't tried the method explained there so thanks for the re-direct!

Comment: it seems that I've been using the "y" axis to solve all my problems when i should be giving them their own plane of existence in a sense. ill see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my question was satisfied by - Ruud Helderman and am providing an answer to show that my question is resolved, by this video i have been informed of: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxjbYJLAUYU&ab_channel=griffpatch

by using the sprites y axis you could determine the layer of the sprite and consistently do so using an exploit in scratch itself to figure out the layer of which it is on and be should be on.

Comment: Links may become nonfunctional over time, so I would advise you to share the gist of their content in your answer.